# Transition doesn't happen when Tailwind classes are changed by Stimulus

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, stimulusjs

When I change a Tailwind class with Stimulus, the styling updates, but there is no transition:

Here is my JavaScript:

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';                                                                                                                                                                                                     

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ['menu'];                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    toggle() {
        if (this.menuTarget.classList.contains('hidden')) {
            this.menuTarget.classList.remove('hidden');                                                                                                                                                                                              
            this.menuTarget.classList.remove('opacity-0');                                                                                                                                                                                           
            this.menuTarget.classList.remove('-translate-y-10');                                                                                                                                                                                     
            return;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        }
        this.menuTarget.classList.add('hidden');                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        this.menuTarget.classList.add('opacity-0');                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        this.menuTarget.classList.add('-translate-y-10');                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```html
<div data-controller="hour-menu">
  <div data-action="click->hour-menu#toggle" class="rounded-full p-2 transition ease-out hover:bg-gray-300">
    <svg class="...">...</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="rounded-md bg-white absolute shadow-md py-1 hidden transition ease-in-out" data-hour-menu-target="menu">...</div>
</div>
```

The `hidden` class is preventing the transition, but if I remove it, the menu items could still be clicked, even when the menu was closed (the menu would only be invisible).

Is there any way to fix this?

(The `hidden` class sets `display:none`)

Comment: This is a well known problem, you cannot transition from `display: none;` to any other display value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property You have to craft your own trick in order to make it look as your div is no longer displayed. Remember that `display: none;` will remove your element from the flow, which is not the case with `opacity` set to `0` for example. Then requires more tweaks to really make the element disappear. Some techniques involves animation / keyframes as animation is replayed when element is leaving `display : none;`